# How do set a Label to type Float so I can have the Label portray slider value (Xcode Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, string, label

Im trying to get a label to portray a slider value, I'm guessing i need a button and then put it in the function, but then it tells me "cannot assign value of type 'Float' to type 'String?'" I'm guessing i need to tell the label it should be a Float so it can be number.

```
 @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: Any) {

  label.text = slider.value

}
```

// second try, this is in red: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

```
@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!


@IBAction func submitValue(_ sender: Any) {

 label.text = String(slider.value)
}
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: IOS Swift Xcode

Answer (score 0):

How about casting Float to String?

```
@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: Any) {

   label.text = String(slider.value)

}
```

Comment: Sometimes broken linkage between IBOutlet/IBAction causes that error. Check that you don't have for example some old links between IBOutlet/IBAction and code.

Comment: So far I can see everything is linked to code, does the order matter on story  board maybe or in scenes?

Comment: I deleted the button and label and i didn't get the error anymore, so maybe i didn't put them in correctly